# Which points lie on the prependicular bisector of (-1,-6) and (5,-8)

Tags: geometry

$A$ and $B$ are the points $(-1,-6)$ and $(5,-8)$, respectively.

Which of the following points lie on the perpendicular bisector of AB?

$P(3,-4)$

$Q(4,0)$

$R(5,2)$

$S(6,5)$

Midpoint of $ AB = (\frac {-1+5}{2} , \frac {-8+(-6)}{2}) = (2,-7) $

Gradient of $AB = \frac {-8-(-1)}{5-(-1)}  = -\frac{7}{6} $

Hence, gradient of perpendicular line = $\frac{6}{7}$

$\therefore $  equation of perpendicular bisector = $$y-(-7) = \frac{6}{7}(x-2)$$

$$y=\frac{6}{7}x-\frac{61}{7}$$

However, by fitting those numbers for $P,Q,R$ and $S$ (above) I find that none satisfy the equation, although the problem book states that $P,R$ and $S$ should.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Your gradient calculation is wrong.

Comment: Oh my word that's dumb - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distances between any point$(h,k)$ on the perpendicular bisector of $A(-1.-6),B(5,-8)$

So, $\sqrt{(h+1)^2+(k+6)^2}=\sqrt{(h-5)^2+(k+8)^2}$

$\iff 12h-4k=52\iff3h-k=13$

So, the locus of $(h,k)$ or the equation of the perpendicular bisector will be $3x-y=13$

Answer (score 0):

The slope of a perpendicular line that bisects is the $r$
slope: $-8-(-6) / 5-(-1)) = 2/6 = 1/3$
slope reciprocal (slope of bisector) $= 3$

midpoint $= (-1+5 / 2) , (-6+(-8) / 2) = (2,-7)$

equation of bisector:
$y=mx+b$
$-7=3(2)+b$
$b=-13$

$y=3x-13$
Slope of bisector line is $3$, so find the other points.

Comment: $-8-(-6)$ is ??